# change spinner's text size by changing resolution

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner.i wanna when device resolution will be change,it's size and it's text size will be change too.
I created some dimens.xml files in Values,Values-large and Values-Xlarge folders and solved it's size.
but now i can not change it's text size.how can i do it ? changing it's text size by changing resolution.

**XML:**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_first"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/spinnerwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinnerheight"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1" />
```

**Code:**

```
 mui.adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,    mui.array_spinner);
 mui.spinner_first.setAdapter(mui.adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make custom xml file for your spinner item.

give your customized size to text in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FF0000"         
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

Now use this file to show your spinner items like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```